# Save graphs (facet) on multiple pages

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet, ggforce

I need to represent an important number of graphs. To do that I used a the `facet_wrap_paginate` function, but I only have the second page printed/plotted.

Here is a sample of my data:

```
df <- structure(list(oxygen = c(60.86414, 62.50372, 89.76055, 61.15914, 
61.49936, 61.90402, 61.60323, 61.2873, 75.12329, 60.83503, 63.03796, 
61.78298, 70.16533, 62.60887, 61.49043, 64.42095, 61.78358, 62.29302, 
62.88122, 60.47264, 65.92805, 65.0235, 64.32414, 65.56869, 64.65729, 
66.73502, 67.01285, 67.47757, 69.62232, 66.09624, 66.18106, 64.28226, 
64.85658, 67.46348, 68.93226, 65.23919, 65.67461, 64.64727, 64.90544, 
68.10878, 70.00292, 59.54631, 61.43627, 78.75032, 61.94263, 82.08963, 
62.75281, 61.93749, 72.86382, 62.06785, 61.04865, 95.49206, 69.79339, 
66.82354, 61.53702, 85.51962, 101.53748, 61.64096, 92.14781, 
60.41892, 77.55303, 75.39007, 62.15703, 82.38292, 87.27823, 69.28644, 
73.72369, 62.02667, 61.34973, 61.61716, 70.61777, 61.59655, 60.31008, 
61.65777, 71.82138, 61.9823, 79.38791, 60.31816, 108.2866, 61.54543, 
69.87043, 64.30304, 65.05726, 68.69304, 84.0604, 121.05592, 68.67872, 
69.53102, 68.31013, 64.76675, 122.22451, 91.29598, 69.43838, 
68.73515, 77.99483, 68.56142, 64.14964, 73.2695, 69.67608, 69.01853, 
68.5685, 63.9001, 68.93557, 71.84125, 72.73052, 69.17045, 76.28085, 
68.41978, 69.53005, 76.15901, 86.43705, 72.95997, 64.0582, 70.29805, 
64.10386, 88.09503, 68.07687, 69.62147, 67.77802, 125.09757, 
91.96934, 97.26108, 89.16293, 80.245, 124.97964, 97.28237, 95.95074, 
99.24807, 82.59685, 89.2217, 77.50349, 88.54909, 91.61343, 77.38885, 
94.06567, 84.77561, 80.46941, 92.28428, 74.25416, 97.07623), 
    depth = c(707.5, 195, 47.5, 750, 315.5, 506.5, 660.5, 678, 
    146, 821.5, 197, 365, 141.5, 448, 574.5, 325.5, 645.5, 236, 
    446, 872.5, 315, 729.5, 786.5, 573.5, 752, 202, 455, 412, 
    147, 552.5, 517, 904, 339.5, 184, 308.5, 307.5, 610, 705.5, 
    700, 375, 228.5, 261.5, 398.5, 168.5, 360, 136.5, 504, 299.5, 
    187, 473.5, 249.5, 64.5, 178.5, 251.5, 369.5, 95, 66.5, 599.5, 
    72, 474, 178, 33.5, 109, 86.5, 26.5, 240, 51.5, 367, 295.5, 
    408.5, 244.5, 106, 314, 304.5, 69.5, 361.5, 91.5, 125.5, 
    11, 281.5, 101.5, 472.5, 433, 257, 24, 6, 192.5, 265, 226, 
    449, 1.5, 21.5, 362.5, 238.5, 33, 246, 477.5, 46, 109, 315, 
    275.5, 636, 284.5, 267, 387, 336.5, 225.5, 291, 205, 136, 
    60.5, 171, 515.5, 260.5, 563, 50, 436, 123, 227, 7.5, 12, 
    87, 32.5, 239, 14.5, 103.5, 90.5, 120.5, 38.5, 36.5, 406, 
    38.5, 143.5, 371, 87, 54.5, 234, 53.5, 260.5, 123), ctd_file = c("BA16007", 
    "BA16002", "BA16011", "BA16003", "BA16004", "BA16006", "BA16001", 
    "BA16002", "BA16012", "BA16003", "BA16004", "BA16004", "BA16005", 
    "BA16004", "BA16009", "BA16005", "BA16012", "BA16004", "BA16006", 
    "BA16003", "BA16013", "BA16014", "BA16017", "BA16016", "BA16018", 
    "BA16016", "BA16014", "BA16020", "BA16020", "BA16020", "BA16016", 
    "BA16018", "BA16016", "BA16018", "BA16021", "BA16015", "BA16014", 
    "BA16013", "BA16015", "BA16021", "BA16025", "BA16023", "BA16024", 
    "BA16025", "BA16024", "BA16025", "BA16025", "BA16025", "BA16024", 
    "BA16025", "BA16023", "BA16025", "BA16023", "BA16025", "BA16024", 
    "BA16022", "BA16022", "BA16025", "BA16024", "BA16024", "BA16026", 
    "BA16035", "BA16030", "BA16035", "BA16031", "BA16026", "BA16032", 
    "BA16031", "BA16027", "BA16032", "BA16035", "BA16028", "BA16031", 
    "BA16027", "BA16033", "BA16032", "BA16035", "BA16028", "BA16027", 
    "BA16032", "BA16034", "BA16034", "BA16034", "BA16034", "BA16034", 
    "BA16034", "BA16034", "BA16034", "BA16034", "BA16034", "BA16034", 
    "BA16034", "BA16034", "BA16034", "BA16034", "BA16034", "BA16034", 
    "BA16034", "BA16034", "BA16034", "BA16040", "BA16036", "BA16043", 
    "BA16047", "BA16048", "BA16041", "BA16049", "BA16036", "BA16042", 
    "BA16044", "BA16048", "BA16045", "BA16039", "BA16046", "BA16036", 
    "BA16048", "BA16044", "BA16038", "BA16041", "BA16045", "BA16052", 
    "BA16055", "BA16054", "BA16054", "BA16053", "BA16053", "BA16053", 
    "BA16055", "BA16055", "BA16053", "BA16055", "BA16054", "BA16052", 
    "BA16055", "BA16054", "BA16053", "BA16054", "BA16055", "BA16052", 
    "BA16053"), Transect = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
    4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 
    5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
    5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
    6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
    7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L), .Label = c("1", 
    "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7"), class = "factor"), Station = structure(c(7L, 
    2L, 11L, 3L, 4L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 12L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 9L, 
    5L, 12L, 4L, 6L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 4L, 2L, 8L, 8L, 
    8L, 4L, 6L, 4L, 6L, 9L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 9L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
    3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 
    3L, 1L, 9L, 5L, 9L, 6L, 1L, 7L, 6L, 2L, 7L, 9L, 3L, 6L, 2L, 
    8L, 7L, 9L, 3L, 2L, 7L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 8L, 
    9L, 3L, 10L, 1L, 4L, 5L, 9L, 6L, 1L, 7L, 1L, 9L, 5L, 1L, 
    3L, 6L, 3L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 6L, 6L, 4L, 6L, 5L, 3L, 
    6L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 3L, 4L), .Label = c("1", "2", "3", "4", 
    "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
-140L), groups = structure(list(Transect = structure(1:7, .Label = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7"), class = "factor"), .rows = structure(list(
    1:20, 21:40, 41:60, 61:80, 81:100, 101:120, 121:140), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
"vctrs_vctr", "list"))), row.names = c(NA, -7L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

And there is the code I used:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyverse)
library(ggforce)

i <- ceiling(
  length(levels(df$Transect)) / 4) # set the number of pages

pdf("multi_page.pdf", width = 16 / 2.54, height = 12 / 2.54)
SdesGG <- df %>% #launch each time or does not work
  group_by(Transect) %>% #mandatory or need to fortify 
  ggplot(aes(x = oxygen, y = depth, color = Station)) +
  geom_line() +
  scale_color_brewer(palette = "Paired") +
  scale_y_reverse() + 
  facet_wrap_paginate(~Transect, ncol = 2, nrow = 2, page = i) #ggforce 
dev.off()
```

I have 180 000 observations, therefore it might be interesting to duplicate the number of row

```
lapply(df, rep, 1000)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the `page` argument you only specify

> The page to draw (see `?facet_wrap_paginate`)

That's why you get only the last or second page with `page = i`.

If you want all pages you have to loop over the pages:

```r
library(ggplot2
library(ggforce)

i <- ceiling(
  length(levels(df$Transect)) / 4) # set the number of pages

pdf("multi_page.pdf", width = 16 / 2.54, height = 12 / 2.54)
lapply(seq(i), function(page) {
  SdesGG <- df %>% #launch each time or does not work
    group_by(Transect) %>% #mandatory or need to fortify 
    ggplot(aes(x = oxygen, y = depth, color = Station)) +
    geom_line() +
    scale_color_brewer(palette = "Paired") +
    scale_y_reverse() + 
    facet_wrap_paginate(~Transect, ncol = 2, nrow = 2, page = page) #ggforce   
})
dev.off()

#> [[1]]
```

[image]

```
#> 
#> [[2]]
```

[image]